# How can i get session data through .net core on react component

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, session-state, tsx

1. I have set the session in the controller  and now I want get that
   session info in the react page i-e layout component.
2. This is my login action on controller.

   ```
   public IActionResult Login(LoginModel loginModel)
       {

           if (_loginRepository.Login(loginModel.Email, loginModel.Password) == true)
           {
               var user = _context.AgencyAdminUser.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == loginModel.Email);
               var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("YourKey-2374-OFFKDI940NG7:56753253-tyuw-5769-0921-kfirox29zoxv");
               //Generate Token for user - JRozario
               var JWToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
                   issuer: "http://localhost:45092/",
                   audience: "http://localhost:45092/",
                   claims: GetUserClaims(user),
                   notBefore: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).DateTime,
                   expires: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)).DateTime,
                   //Using HS256 Algorithm to encrypt Token - JRozario
                   signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
               );
               var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(JWToken);
               if (token != null)
               {
                   //Save token in session object
                   HttpContext.Session.SetString("JWToken", token);
               }
               return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
           }
           else
           {
               ViewBag.Message = "Enter Valid Email Address!";
               return View();
           }

       }
   ```
3. and this is the my layout react component

   ```
   import * as React from 'react';
   import { NavMenu } from './NavMenu';


   export interface LayoutProps {
       children?: React.ReactNode;
   }


   export class Layout extends React.Component<LayoutProps, {}> {

       public render() {
           return <div className='kt-quick-panel--right kt-demo-panel--right kt-offcanvas-panel--right kt-header--fixed kt-header-mobile--fixed kt-subheader--fixed kt-subheader--enabled kt-subheader--solid kt-aside--enabled kt-aside--fixed kt-page--loading'>
               <div className='d-grid kt-grid--hor kt-grid--root'>
                   <div className='kt-grid__item kt-grid__item--fluid kt-grid kt-grid--ver kt-page'>
                       <NavMenu />
                   </div>
                   <div className="kt-grid__item kt-grid__item--fluid kt-grid kt-grid--hor kt-wrapper" id="kt_wrapper">
                       <div id="kt_header" className="kt-header kt-grid__item  kt-header--fixed ">
                           <button className="kt-header-menu-wrapper-close" id="kt_header_menu_mobile_close_btn"><i className="la la-close"></i></button>
                           <div className="kt-header-menu-wrapper" id="kt_header_menu_wrapper">

                               <div id="kt_header_menu" className="kt-header-menu kt-header-menu-mobile  kt-header-menu--layout-default ">
                                   <ul className="kt-menu__nav ">
                                       <li className="kt-menu__item  kt-menu__item--open kt-menu__item--here kt-menu__item--submenu kt-menu__item--rel kt-menu__item--open kt-menu__item--here kt-menu__item--active" data-ktmenu-submenu-toggle="click" aria-haspopup="true"><a href="javascript:;" className="kt-menu__link kt-menu__toggle"><span className="kt-menu__link-text">Pages</span><i className="kt-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i></a>
                                           <div className="kt-menu__submenu kt-menu__submenu--classic kt-menu__submenu--left">
                                               <ul className="kt-menu__subnav">
                                                   <li className="kt-menu__item  kt-menu__item--active " aria-haspopup="true"><a href="index.html" className="kt-menu__link "><span className="kt-menu__link-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" className="kt-svg-icon">
                                                       <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                                           <rect id="bound" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" />
                                                           <path d="M5.84026576,8 L18.1597342,8 C19.1999115,8 20.0664437,8.79732479 20.1528258,9.83390904 L20.8194924,17.833909 C20.9112219,18.9346631 20.0932459,19.901362 18.9924919,19.9930915 C18.9372479,19.9976952 18.8818364,20 18.8264009,20 L5.1735991,20 C4.0690296,20 3.1735991,19.1045695 3.1735991,18 C3.1735991,17.9445645 3.17590391,17.889153 3.18050758,17.833909 L3.84717425,9.83390904 C3.93355627,8.79732479 4.80008849,8 5.84026576,8 Z M10.5,10 C10.2238576,10 10,10.2238576 10,10.5 L10,11.5 C10,11.7761424 10.2238576,12 10.5,12 L13.5,12 C13.7761424,12 14,11.7761424 14,11.5 L14,10.5 C14,10.2238576 13.7761424,10 13.5,10 L10.5,10 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#000000" />
                                                           <path d="M10,8 L8,8 L8,7 C8,5.34314575 9.34314575,4 11,4 L13,4 C14.6568542,4 16,5.34314575 16,7 L16,8 L14,8 L14,7 C14,6.44771525 13.5522847,6 13,6 L11,6 C10.4477153,6 10,6.44771525 10,7 L10,8 Z" id="Path-53" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" opacity="0.3" />
                                                       </g>
                                                   </svg></span><span className="kt-menu__link-text">My Account</span></a></li>
                                                   <li className="kt-menu__item " aria-haspopup="true"><a href="javascript:;" className="kt-menu__link "><span className="kt-menu__link-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" className="kt-svg-icon">
                                                       <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                                           <rect id="bound" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" />
                                                           <path d="M2.56066017,10.6819805 L4.68198052,8.56066017 C5.26776695,7.97487373 6.21751442,7.97487373 6.80330086,8.56066017 L8.9246212,10.6819805 C9.51040764,11.267767 9.51040764,12.2175144 8.9246212,12.8033009 L6.80330086,14.9246212 C6.21751442,15.5104076 5.26776695,15.5104076 4.68198052,14.9246212 L2.56066017,12.8033009 C1.97487373,12.2175144 1.97487373,11.267767 2.56066017,10.6819805 Z M14.5606602,10.6819805 L16.6819805,8.56066017 C17.267767,7.97487373 18.2175144,7.97487373 18.8033009,8.56066017 L20.9246212,10.6819805 C21.5104076,11.267767 21.5104076,12.2175144 20.9246212,12.8033009 L18.8033009,14.9246212 C18.2175144,15.5104076 17.267767,15.5104076 16.6819805,14.9246212 L14.5606602,12.8033009 C13.9748737,12.2175144 13.9748737,11.267767 14.5606602,10.6819805 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#000000" opacity="0.3" />
                                                           <path d="M8.56066017,16.6819805 L10.6819805,14.5606602 C11.267767,13.9748737 12.2175144,13.9748737 12.8033009,14.5606602 L14.9246212,16.6819805 C15.5104076,17.267767 15.5104076,18.2175144 14.9246212,18.8033009 L12.8033009,20.9246212 C12.2175144,21.5104076 11.267767,21.5104076 10.6819805,20.9246212 L8.56066017,18.8033009 C7.97487373,18.2175144 7.97487373,17.267767 8.56066017,16.6819805 Z M8.56066017,4.68198052 L10.6819805,2.56066017 C11.267767,1.97487373 12.2175144,1.97487373 12.8033009,2.56066017 L14.9246212,4.68198052 C15.5104076,5.26776695 15.5104076,6.21751442 14.9246212,6.80330086 L12.8033009,8.9246212 C12.2175144,9.51040764 11.267767,9.51040764 10.6819805,8.9246212 L8.56066017,6.80330086 C7.97487373,6.21751442 7.97487373,5.26776695 8.56066017,4.68198052 Z" id="Combined-Shape" fill="#000000" />
                                                       </g>
                                                   </svg></span><span className="kt-menu__link-text">Task Manager</span><span className="kt-menu__link-badge"><span className="kt-badge kt-badge--success">2</span></span></a></li>
                                                   <li className="kt-menu__item  kt-menu__item--submenu" data-ktmenu-submenu-toggle="hover" aria-haspopup="true"><a href="javascript:;" className="kt-menu__link kt-menu__toggle"><span className="kt-menu__link-icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" className="kt-svg-icon">
                                                       <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                                                           <rect id="bound" x="0" y="0" width="24" height="24" />
                                                           <path d="M9,15 L7.5,15 C6.67157288,15 6,15.6715729 6,16.5 C6,17.3284271 6.67157288,18 7.5,18 C8.32842712,18 9,17.3284271 9,16.5 L9,15 Z M9,15 L9,9 L15,9 L15,15 L9,15 Z M15,16.5 C15,17.3284271 15.6715729,18 16.5,18 C17.3284271,18 18,17.3284271 18,16.5 C18,15.6715729 17.3284271,15 16.5,15 L15,15 L15,16.5 Z M16.5,9 C17.3284271,9 18,8.32842712 18,7.5 C18,6.67157288 17.3284271,6 16.5,6 C15.6715729,6 15,6.67157288 15,7.5 L15,9 L16.5,9 Z M9,7.5 C9,6.67157288 8.32842712,6 7.5,6 C6.67157288,6 6,6.67157288 6,7.5 C6,8.32842712 6.67157288,9 7.5,9 L9,9 L9,7.5 Z M11,13 L13,13 L13,11 L11,11 L11,13 Z M13,11 L13,7.5 C13,5.56700338 14.5670034,4 16.5,4 C18.4329966,4 20,5.56700338 20,7.5 C20,9.43299662 18.4329966,11 16.5,11 L13,11 Z M16.5,13 C18.4329966,13 20,14.5670034 20,16.5 C20,18.4329966 18.4329966,20 16.5,20 C14.5670034,20 13,18.4329966 13,16.5 L13,13 L16.5,13 Z M11,16.5 C11,18.4329966 9.43299662,20 7.5,20 C5.56700338,20 4,18.4329966 4,16.5 C4,14.5670034 5.56700338,13 7.5,13 L11,13 L11,16.5 Z M7.5,11 C5.56700338,11 4,9.43299662 4,7.5 C4,5.56700338 5.56700338,4 7.5,4 C9.43299662,4 11,5.56700338 11,7.5 L11,11 L7.5,11 Z" id="Path-2" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" />
                                                       </g>
                                                   </svg></span><span className="kt-menu__link-text">Team Manager</span><i className="kt-menu__hor-arrow la la-angle-right"></i><i className="kt-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i></a>
                                                       <div className="kt-menu__submenu kt-menu__submenu--classic kt-menu__submenu--right">
                                                           <ul className="kt-menu__subnav">
                                                               <li className="kt-menu__item " aria-haspopup="true"><a href="javascript:;" className="kt-menu__link "><i className="kt-menu__link-bullet kt-menu__link-bullet--dot"><span></span></i><span className="kt-menu__link-text">Add Team Member</span></a></li>
                                                               <li className="kt-menu__item " aria-haspopup="true"><a href="javascript:;" className="kt-menu__link "><i className="kt-menu__link-bullet kt-menu__link-bullet--dot"><span></span></i><span className="kt-menu__link-text">Edit Team Member</span></a></li>
                                                               <li className="kt-menu__item " aria-haspopup="true"><a href="javascript:;" className="kt-menu__link "><i className="kt-menu__link-bullet kt-menu__link-bullet--dot"><span></span></i><span className="kt-menu__link-text">Delete Team Member</span></a></li>
                                                               <li className="kt-menu__item " aria-haspopup="true"><a href="javascript:;" className="kt-menu__link "><i className="kt-menu__link-bullet kt-menu__link-bullet--dot"><span></span></i><span className="kt-menu__link-text">Team Member Reports</span></a></li>
                                                               <li className="kt-menu__item " aria-haspopup="true"><a href="javascript:;" className="kt-menu__link "><i className="kt-menu__link-bullet kt-menu__link-bullet--dot"><span></span></i><span className="kt-menu__link-text">Assign Tasks</span></a></li>
                                                               <li className="kt-menu__item " aria-haspopup="true"><a href="javascript:;" className="kt-menu__link "><i className="kt-menu__link-bullet kt-menu__link-bullet--dot"><span></span></i><span className="kt-menu__link-text">Promote Team Member</span></a></li>
   ```
4. I want to use FirstName in the component code above which is stored
   in the session info;

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs is client side and your .net core code is server side.

Session variables cannot be accessed directly from Reactjs. Better add your required values to a cookie and access them with ReactJs